# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application - python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

python file

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

#lib = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Users\\Ali\\Desktop\\test9\\a.dll")
lib = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Users\\Ali\\Desktop\\test9\\a.dll")

#lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(4000,3),flags='C')
lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(100000000,3),flags='C')
#
res = lib.function()
print(res)
```

c file(dll)

```
 int (*function(void))[3] {
     clock_t begin = clock();
     // allocate an array of 5 arrays of 5 int
     int (*information)[3] = malloc(100000000 * sizeof(*information));
     // initialize all 5 rows to identical vectors { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
     for (int k = 0; k < 100000000; k++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             information[k][j] = j;
         }
     }
     clock_t end = clock();
     double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     printf("%f\n", time_spent);
     return information;
 }
```

When I try to use the dll it gives me this error even though I'm sure mingw64 is installed

Is my problem from c script?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the compilation code
im used gcc -shared -o a.dll main.c instead of gcc -c -fPIC main.c -o a.dll

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? Cause *-shared* is required to build a *.dll*.